# Sqlalchemy query to array column using LIKE

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-like

I have table File with column file_names which is ARRAY type. W would like to build query searching records where any of array element is like "abc*" using wildcard.

I tried:

```
File.names.any("abc%", operator= operators.like_op).all()
```

but it doesn't work.
It return sql:

```
SELECT file.id, file.names FROM file WHERE 'abc%' LIKE ANY(file.names)
```

but it return empty result.
Do you have any suggestions, how to build such query?

Answer (score 1):

The `like` operator applies to a text, not to an array, so you need to find a way to convert your array into text before applying the `like` operator. To do so in sql you can use `array_to_string()` function, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html).

For example :

`select array_to_string('{"name_1", "name_2", "name_3"}' :: text[], ' ') LIKE '%name_2%'` returns `true`.

The first character `%` is mandatory because the searched word may be at any place in the string which results from the array.

Then you can add the separator specified in the `array_to_string()` function before and after the searched word (`LIKE '% name2 %'`) in order to exclude the results like `somename_2`.

For example :

`select array_to_string('{"name_1", "name_2", "name_3"}' :: text[], ' ') LIKE '% name_2 %'` returns `true`

but

`select array_to_string('{"name_1", "somename_2", "name_3"}' :: text[], ' ') LIKE '% name_2 %'` returns `false`.

Last but not least, for the seprator, you can specifiy a non printable character like `chr(12)` or a set of characters instead of the space character in order to secure the results of the query.

Comment: But I try to ask about elements of ARRAY which are strings and use LIKE to every element in ARRAY. If we say about array_to_string(), when I concatenate all elements the query with LIKE to this concatenated string doesn't give such efect as for every element separately.

Comment: @Wald, when using the `array_to_string()` function, you can specify the delimiter as a text, either with non printable ascii characters such as chr(12) or with a sequence of characters that cannot appear in the array elements. I would suggest the first solution.

Comment: f.e column names has value ['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3']. After array_to_string() if I query for 'name_2%' I don't get this record because before 'name_2' is 'name_1', so it doesn't match pattern despite array element match pattern. It is a problem.

Comment: `select array_to_string('{"name_1", "name_2", "name_3"}' :: text[], ' ') LIKE '%name_2%'`returns `true`

Comment: You are right. But I don't want to ask about `'%name_2%'` but ask for `name_2%`, because I'm not interesting in results f.e somename_2

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in SQL:

```
SELECT file.id, file.names FROM file WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM unnest(file.names) AS n
WHERE n LIKE 'abc%')
```